# Learning C++ in an iterator-based fashion: Good for gaining a background, but is it practical for gaining a job?

Tags: c++

I know this sounds like an opinion-based question, but I think it's specific enough since it's a question about real-life C++ implementation.

I'm a Mathematics student at college and I've been trying to teach myself C++ and I want to get an entry-level programming job in an environment that uses it. I've been learning from the book *C++ Primer Plus, Sixth Edition*, which I think is a great book because it goes into a lot of details about what's happening at the machine level and goes into the history of C and all that nitty-gritty stuff that's helping me become a "real" programmer.

I've applied for some jobs that look perfect for me, such as *Entry-Level C++ Programmer* at Nintendo. It seems like a lot of gaming companies use C++.

Here's the thing: I've learned C++ in a pointer-based fashion because that's how my book teaches it. I'm well aware, from reading Stack Overflow and seeing code samples other places on the web, that C++11 has given the language high-level capabilities such as using `auto` to iterate through the elements of a data structure.

So I'm wondering, if I have an interview at Nintendo and I do something like

```
for (std::vector::iterator it1(V.begin()), it2(V.end()); it1 != it2; ++it1)
```

instead of

```
for (auto it : V)
```

will I thrown out of the interview and laughed at? Is using pointer-based code obsolete? My brain is trained to do things the `C++ Primer` way, which is iterators/pointers. I understand this is good to know, but for practicality sake, should I get used to doing C++11 stuff?

Comment: You aren't showing any pointer-based code. Referring to an iterator-based loop like that wouldn't do you much good in an interview. Other than that, do a search for opinions on the book you're using. I've only heard bad things about it. But I have not verified this personally.

Comment: Well nintendo are a bad example because they're still using code warrior so I doubt they even support C++03 let alone 11 ;)  Their code samples are fairly universally C, however.

Comment: Code quality transcends languages or versions thereof. There are beautiful code examples that use K&R C, just like there are really awful code examples that use C++11. Showing that you are aware of and can use C++11 features can be a plus, but if your interviewer / reviewer is the least bit competent, what he will be looking at is code quality, and that's what you should be focusing on. A good start for this is [C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm). And good knowledge and use of STL algorithms is critical too.

Comment: You might get some remarks that `std::vector::iterator` is missing the template argument, and `for (auto it : V)` copies each element.

Answer (score 4):

> should I get used to doing C++11 stuff?

Certainly you should! It's the actual **standard**.

Though to work in practice (especially in legacy or embedded environments), you should know how to build and use workarounds for outdated toolchains that don't support the actual standard.

That said, your question is not opinion-based, the answer is pretty much steered by the current situation in the C++ field.
I don't think anyone would laugh at you. But you might gain extra points, when you present both answers.

<sub>**Honestly:**

The first thing I'm judging an interview answer about code is:

Does it answer the question as intended, and is everything syntactically and semantically correct.

Other major points are:

* Knowledge of the C++ standard library (in general)

* Creativity and ability to abstract out situations and patterns</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You won't be thrown away for not using C++11, if that is the question. I know very few companies (and, well, C++ developers) that actually use it. It will take time before C++11 becomes the de *facto standard.*

Anyway, for a junior position, you shouldn't be worried about that all that much. Better focus on a working code than a fancy one.